# Invoke-WebRequest return only 100 value

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, invoke-webrequest

I run this code and only returning the first 100 records, not sure why.

Can you please advise?

I belive this is what I should modify but don't know how:

```
$select=displayName,userPrincipalName,signInActivity
```

This is the full code:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Headers $AuthHeader1 -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?`$select=displayName,userPrincipalName,signInActivity" -UseBasicParsing
```

Update:

```
$LastLogin = Invoke-WebRequest -Headers $AuthHeader1 -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?`$top=999&$select=displayName,userPrincipalName,signInActivity&$skiptoken=Paged=TRUE&$odata.nextlink" -UseBasicParsing

$NextLink = $LastLogin."@odata.nextLink"
$LastLoginpage2 = Invoke-WebRequest -Method Get -Headers $AuthHeader1 -Uri '$NextLink' -UseBasicParsing
```

Thanks.

Gabor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default every API has its own [limit per page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/paging) to give number of records as a response. Here the `/users` gives 100 users per page and additionally it gives a @odata.nextLink as a reference to the next page as shown below in the image.

[image]

You can use the odata.nextLink and make another call and get the next page of users.

If you want to modify the limit per page, you can use [$top query parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#top-parameter) to get 200 or 300 user objects per page. Use the below query to get 200 records per page.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$top=200&$select=displayName,userPrincipalName,signInActivity
```

Comment: Thanks, now I'm facing the issue that only 1000 user that I can query in a single request.

Comment: Have any advice on how to request all on the in a single query?

Comment: Yes, the API works as specify in the pagination. So you can specify the limits per page (maximum you will get 999), then use the odata.nextlink, make another call to get the next page of users.

Comment: I use this:
$LastLogin = Invoke-WebRequest -Headers $AuthHeader1 -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?`$top=999&$select=displayName,userPrincipalName,signInActivity&$skiptoken=Paged=TRUE&$odata.nextlink" -UseBasicParsing

$NextLink = $LastLogin."@odata.nextLink"
$LastLoginpage2 = Invoke-WebRequest -Method Get -Headers $AuthHeader1 -Uri '$NextLink' -UseBasicParsing

Comment: seem like when I try to get the next link the variable is empty. I also add this code the top so you can see better